# Custom Transformers and GridSearch - ValueError in Pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search

I'm trying to optimise hyperparameters in a scikit-learn Pipeline, with a few custom transformers but I keep on getting an error:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

class RollingMeanTransform(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, col, window=3):
        self._window = window
        self._col = col

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        df = X.copy()
        df['{}_rolling_mean'.format(self._col)] = df[self._col].shift(1).rolling(self._window).mean().fillna(0.0)
        return df


class TimeEncoding(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, col, drop_original=True):
        self._col = col 
        self._drop_original = drop_original

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        X = X.copy()
        unique_vals = float(len(X[self._col].unique()))
        X['sin_{}'.format(self._col)] = np.sin(2 * np.pi * X[self._col] / unique_vals)
        X['cos_{}'.format(self._col)] = np.cos(2 * np.pi * X[self._col] / unique_vals)
        if self._drop_original:
            X.drop([self._col], axis=1, inplace=True, errors='ignore')
        return X


huber = HuberRegressor()
huber_max_iter = [100, 200, 500, 1000]
huber_alpha = [0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1.0, 10, 100]
huber_epsilon = [1.15, 1.25, 1.35, 1.5]

huber_grid = {'clf__alpha':huber_alpha,
              'clf__epsilon':huber_epsilon,
              'clf__max_iter':huber_max_iter,
}

regression_pipeline = Pipeline([('encoding', TimeEncoding('my_col')),
                                ('mean', RollingMeanTransform('my_other_col')), 
                                ('select', Treshold()),
                                ('scale', Scale()),
                                ('clf', huber)
])
```

I try fitting this with:

```
grid = GridSearchCV(regression_pipeline, huber_grid, cv=TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=5))
grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

But I get the following expception:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-3949096c802a> in <module>()
----> 1 grid.fit(X_train, y_train)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    637                                   error_score=self.error_score)
    638           for parameters, (train, test) in product(candidate_params,
--> 639                                                    cv.split(X, y, groups)))
    640 
    641         # if one choose to see train score, "out" will contain train score info

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
    777             # was dispatched. In particular this covers the edge
    778             # case of Parallel used with an exhausted iterator.
--> 779             while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
    780                 self._iterating = True
    781             else:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    623                 return False
    624             else:
--> 625                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    626                 return True
    627 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    586         dispatch_timestamp = time.time()
    587         cb = BatchCompletionCallBack(dispatch_timestamp, len(batch), self)
--> 588         job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    589         self._jobs.append(job)
    590 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    109     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    110         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 111         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    112         if callback:
    113             callback(result)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    330         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    331         # arguments in memory
--> 332         self.results = batch()
    333 
    334     def get(self):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self)
    129 
    130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    132 
    133     def __len__(self):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    129 
    130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    132 
    133     def __len__(self):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in _fit_and_score(estimator, X, y, scorer, train, test, verbose, parameters, fit_params, return_train_score, return_parameters, return_n_test_samples, return_times, error_score)
    456             estimator.fit(X_train, **fit_params)
    457         else:
--> 458             estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
    459 
    460     except Exception as e:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    246             This estimator
    247         """
--> 248         Xt, fit_params = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params)
    249         if self._final_estimator is not None:
    250             self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in _fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    211                 Xt, fitted_transformer = fit_transform_one_cached(
    212                     cloned_transformer, None, Xt, y,
--> 213                     **fit_params_steps[name])
    214                 # Replace the transformer of the step with the fitted
    215                 # transformer. This is necessary when loading the transformer

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/memory.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    360 
    361     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 362         return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
    363 
    364     def call_and_shelve(self, *args, **kwargs):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in _fit_transform_one(transformer, weight, X, y, **fit_params)
    579                        **fit_params):
    580     if hasattr(transformer, 'fit_transform'):
--> 581         res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
    582     else:
    583         res = transformer.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    518         else:
    519             # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)
--> 520             return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)
    521 
    522 

~/my_project/my_model.py in transform(self, X)
    126     def transform(self, X):
    127         X = X.copy()
--> 128         unique_vals = float(len(X[self._col].unique()))
    129         X['sin_{}'.format(self._col)] = np.sin(2 * np.pi * X[self._col] / unique_vals)
    130         X['cos_{}'.format(self._col)] = np.cos(2 * np.pi * X[self._col] / unique_vals)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2137             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   2138         else:
-> 2139             return self._getitem_column(key)
   2140 
   2141     def _getitem_column(self, key):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _getitem_column(self, key)
   2144         # get column
   2145         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 2146             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   2147 
   2148         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _get_item_cache(self, item)
   1840         res = cache.get(item)
   1841         if res is None:
-> 1842             values = self._data.get(item)
   1843             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
   1844             cache[item] = res

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in get(self, item, fastpath)
   3850                         loc = indexer.item()
   3851                     else:
-> 3852                         raise ValueError("cannot label index with a null key")
   3853 
   3854             return self.iget(loc, fastpath=fastpath)

ValueError: cannot label index with a null key
```

​
I have no idea what's going on, or how to fix it. If I remove the transformer it works, but I need this in my pipeline.

If I change the pipeline to be

```
 regression_pipeline = Pipeline([('mean', RollingMeanTransform('my_other_col')), 
                                 ('encoding', TimeEncoding('my_col')),
                                 ('select', Treshold()),
                                 ('scale', Scale()),
                                 ('clf', huber)
    ])
```

I get the same error, but this time called on the `mean` transformer.

The complete code sample:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import HuberRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class RollingMeanTransform(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, col, window=3):
        self._window = window
        self._col = col

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        df = X.copy()
        df['{}_rolling_mean'.format(self._col)] = df[self._col].shift(1).rolling(self._window).mean().fillna(0.0)
        return df


class TimeEncoding(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, col, drop_original=True):
        self._col = col 
        self._drop_original = drop_original

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        X = X.copy()
        unique_vals = float(len(X[self._col].unique()))
        X['sin_{}'.format(self._col)] = np.sin(2 * np.pi * X[self._col] / unique_vals)
        X['cos_{}'.format(self._col)] = np.cos(2 * np.pi * X[self._col] / unique_vals)
        if self._drop_original:
            X.drop([self._col], axis=1, inplace=True, errors='ignore')
        return X

class Treshold(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    # note: Threshold which removes features with constant value
    # and preserves the input data as data frame
    def __init__(self):

        self.to_keep = list()

    def fit(self, X, y=None):


        self.to_keep = list()

        self.colname_original = X.columns

        for i, col in enumerate(X):

            if len(np.unique(X.values[:, i])) >= 2:
                self.to_keep.append(col)

        return self

    def transform(self, X, copy=None):
        return X[self.to_keep]


class Scale(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    # note: scaler which keeps the input data as data frame
    # and does not scale binary features
    def __init__(self, copy=True, with_mean=True, with_std=True):
        self.scaler = StandardScaler(copy, with_mean, with_std)

        self.bin_vars_index = list()
        self.cont_vars_index = list()

        self.colnames_original = list()

    def fit(self, X, y=None):

        self.bin_vars_index = list()
        self.cont_vars_index = list()

        self.colnames_original = list()

        self.colnames_original = X.columns

        for i in range(X.shape[1]):

            if len(np.unique(X.values[:, i])) <= 2:
                self.bin_vars_index.append(i)
            else:
                self.cont_vars_index.append(i)

        self.scaler.fit(X.values[:, self.cont_vars_index])
        return self

    def transform(self, X, copy=None):
        X_tail = self.scaler.transform(X.values[:, self.cont_vars_index], copy)
        res = np.concatenate((X.values[:, self.bin_vars_index], X_tail), axis=1)

        colnames_res = np.array(
            list(self.colnames_original[self.bin_vars_index]) + list(self.colnames_original[self.cont_vars_index]))
        assert len(colnames_res) == len(self.colnames_original)
        res = pd.DataFrame(data=res, columns=colnames_res)
        return res[[str(el) for el in self.colnames_original]].set_index(X.index)



huber = HuberRegressor()
huber_max_iter = [100, 200, 500, 1000]
huber_alpha = [0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1.0, 10, 100]
huber_epsilon = [1.15, 1.25, 1.35, 1.5]

huber_grid = {'clf__alpha':huber_alpha,
              'clf__epsilon':huber_epsilon,
              'clf__max_iter':huber_max_iter,
}

regression_pipeline = Pipeline([('encoding', TimeEncoding('my_col')),
                                ('mean', RollingMeanTransform('my_other_col')), 
                                ('select', Treshold()),
                                ('scale', Scale()),
                                ('clf', huber)
])

grid = GridSearchCV(regression_pipeline, huber_grid, cv=TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=5))

X = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(20, 2)), columns=['my_col', 'my_other_col'])

y = pd.Series(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(20,)))

grid.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: Please post the complete code (including your original dataframe) and some sample data on which this error is happening.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You see the GridSearchCV (and most of the cross-validation utilities in scikit-learn) clone the supplied data to perform the grid-search.

And in doing that they will use the [`get_params()` and `set_params()`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/base.py#L213) of the BaseEstimator class which you are inheriting. Now the `get_params()` will get the parameters from the `__init__()` method you declared.

And this is the [source of get_params()](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/base.py#L198):

```
    init_signature = signature(init)
    # Consider the constructor parameters excluding 'self'
    parameters = [p for p in init_signature.parameters.values()
                  if p.name != 'self' and p.kind != p.VAR_KEYWORD]

    ...
    ...
```

Now to get the values, this is used](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/base.py#L228):

```
    for key in self._get_param_names():
        value = getattr(self, key, None)
```

So the parameters that this will give is:

```
col = None
drop_original = None
```

Not the ones with `leading underscore` that you used. The values are None for both, because your objects dont have any attributes with these names.

Now these None valued parameters will be used to instantiate the cloned objects [`in clone()`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/base.py#L62):

```
...
new_object = klass(**new_object_params)
...
...
```

And then these `None` values will be set to your `_col` and `_drop_original`. Thats the source of error.

This thing has been documented in [the deleloper guidelines in scikit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/contributing.html#estimators):

> The arguments accepted by **init** should all be keyword arguments
>   with a default value. In other words, a user should be able to
>   instantiate an estimator without passing any arguments to it. The
>   arguments should all correspond to hyperparameters describing the
>   model or the optimisation problem the estimator tries to solve.
>
> In addition, every keyword argument accepted by **init** should
>   correspond to an attribute on the instance. Scikit-learn relies on
>   this to find the relevant attributes to set on an estimator when doing
>   model selection.

So the recommended approach to resolve this is remove leading underscore from your param names (so that the names in `__init__` and `self` should be same):

```
class TimeEncoding(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    # Changed the names from _col to col
    def __init__(self, col, drop_original=True):
        self.col = col
        self.drop_original = drop_original

    def transform(self, X):
        X = X.copy()

        # Updated the names to be used
        unique_vals = float(len(X[self.col].unique()))
        X['sin_{}'.format(self.col)] = np.sin(2 * np.pi * X[self.col] / unique_vals)
        X['cos_{}'.format(self.col)] = np.cos(2 * np.pi * X[self.col] / unique_vals)
        if self.drop_original:
            X.drop([self.col], axis=1, inplace=True, errors='ignore')
        return X
```

Now do this for all custom estimators.

Now if you have some limitations to be working with leading underscores for attributes (maybe to try making them private or something similar) your second option is to override the `set_params()` method to explicitly set the parameters.

Comment: Sorry, that's a mistake on my part. I've edited the question. I have several transformers, and it always raises this error on the first one to be called.

Comment: Thank you ever so much! I spent 2 days working on that.